# Numeric Fuzzy Comparison Join in Python/pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-comparison

I have four tables of the production of an airline schedule. I do not actually have the column PK, but I'm putting it there so I can refer to the flights easier. I've got them in pd.DataFrames right now.

Table 1. Draft #1

```
MarketID  Origin Dest FltNum  DepCentral  ArrCentral  PK
1DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  111     0700        1035        A
2DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  222     2035        2410        B
```

Table 2. Draft #2

```
MarketID  Origin Dest FltNum  DepCentral  ArrCentral  PK
1DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  111     0700        1030        A
2DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  222     2040        2410        B
```

Table 3. Draft #3

```
MarketID  Origin Dest FltNum  DepCentral  ArrCentral  PK
1DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  444     0645        1015        A
2DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  555     1300        1630        X
3DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  666     2040        2410        B
```

Table 4. Final Schedule

```
MarketID  Origin Dest FltNum  DepCentral  ArrCentral  PK
1DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  444     0645        1015        A
2DFWSJC   DFW    SJC  666     2040        2415        B
```

I basically want to follow every flight that was in Draft 1 that is also in the final schedule and see how they were altered in the production. But I'm also trying to track the changes made to each flight across each table. Essentially it'd be an inner join and I'd have columns for DepCentral_Draft1, DepCentral_Draft2, etc.

With this I could see that between Draft 1 and 2, flight A had its arrival time moved 5 minutes earlier. Between draft 2 and 3, flight A had its departure and arrival time moved 15 minutes earlier. etc.

MarketID comes close, but between draft #2 and #3, they inserted a flight and relabeled MarketID (it's ordered by departure time). They appear to have added and subtracted flights pretty cavalierly from between Draft #2 and #3 as well as between #3 and Final, so I cannot rely on MarketID.

FltNum is also very inconsistent. Between Draft #1 and #2, they match, but #3 and #4, they seem to randomly relabel the flight number after Draft #3.

As a human I can tell that 2DFWSJC in Table 3 is neither Flight A nor B because of how different its departure/arrival time is. When I was joining on MarketID, it thought that flight B was being moved from 2040 to 1300 (which is how I noticed these insertions).

I cannot concatenate the Origin, Dest, and departure or arrival times and match because they are being slightly shifted around, so they're not exact matches. I have seen fuzzy comparisons done with strings, but I have seen nothing like it with numerics.

Something like defining Flight B as

```
Origin     = DFW  
Dest       = SJC   
DepCentral = ~2035 
ArrCentral = ~2410
```

Where I could either define how close is ~ or it automatically realizes that 2040 is much closer to 2035 than 1300 and joins if possible.

This is the original function I had written to find the difference between the original schedule and the new one.

```
def schdChanges(base, new):
merged = pd.merge(base, new, on = ['MktSegID'])

diffDf = pd.DataFrame()

diffDf['MktSegID'] = merged['MktSegID']
diffDf['Cdep'] = merged['Cdep_y'] - merged['Cdep_x']
diffDf['Carr'] = merged['Carr_y'] - merged['Carr_x']
diffDf['Block'] = merged['Block_y'] - merged['Block_x']
diffDf['Turn'] = merged['Turn_y'] - merged['Turn_x']

return diffDf
```

Edit. Alternative solutions I've had are identifying where the capacity of a market (like DFW-SJC) has changed and only focusing on those.

DirMkt - Origin + Dest

```
Draft1Cap = Draft1.groupby('DirMkt')['MktSegID'].nunique()
FinalCap  = Final.groupby( 'DirMkt')['MktSegID'].nunique()

FinalCap.subtract(Draft1Cap, fill_value = 0)[FinalCap.subtract(Draft1Cap, fill_value = 0) != 0]
```

So now I've identified which ones have changed. My old function works for everything except these then.

And using this I've IDed which markets to remove from the schedule because they do not exist in both the draft and the final

```
def returnNotMatches(a, b):
    return [[x for x in a if x not in b], [x for x in b if x not in a]]  

returnNotMatches(set(Draft1['DirMkt'].unique()), set(Final['DirMkt'].unique()))
```

So basically the bare minimum that I need is to figure out, when a flight is added, where was it added relative to the other flights in its market?

Comment: in numpy, you can find the function [isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) that may give you a direction

Comment: I see your general issue but I'm not clear on your desired output. Is it automatically assigning the PK field? Also, can this be done from one change to another or do all four versions of PK B need to be considered somehow at once? I'm not sure if you need Bayesian statistics. Is your dataset large? Are there 4 changes just in your example or in the actual data.

Comment: @Zev Essentially, yes. I basically want a function that returns a DataFrame where the rows are the unique flights (AKA pk which just stands for primary key) and the columns are just the changes between any two drafts. So I really only need to differences between any two drafts. The dataset is about 4000 rows for each draft which can vary +/- 50 between each draft as flights are added and removed. In reality there are up to 20 drafts, but I'm currently working with 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 6 columns. Let's break them down by how useful they are in this situation.

`MarketID` and `FltNum` can change arbitrarily so that won't help us.
`Origin` and `Dest` I'm going to presume must be the same and can't change, so we'll check for that
`DepCentral` and `ArrCentral` are the most important and per the problem statement can change up to 50 minutes.

You have some complex business logic so there probably isn't a simple solution. So here's where the fun comes in, coding up something to handle that logic!

**This program finds the matches, I'll leave it up to you to get the output how you'd like it**

```
import pandas as pd
```

If you have the dates, or know for sure that you won't have something at 23:55 that needs to match with 00:04 than you can simplify or replace this logic

```
def time_change(old_time, new_time):
    old_hrs, new_hrs = int(old_time[0:2]), int(new_time[0:2])
    old_mins, new_mins = int(old_time[2:]), int(new_time[2:])

    old_total = 60 * old_hrs + old_mins
    new_total = 60 * new_hrs + new_mins

    # note, this may make incorrect assumptions since we don't have the day. 
    # If you have the day in your actual data, there are better ways of comparing the times
    return abs((new_total - old_total)) % (24 * 60)
```

now, to the heart of the matter, checking for a match. You laid out what your are looking for so this is just some logic to implement it. This function takes in any two rows to compare.

```
def check_match(old, new):
    #["MarketID", "Origin", "Dest", "FltNum", "DepCentral", "ArrCentral"]
    if old['Origin'] != new['Origin']:
        return False, "", ""
    if old['Dest'] != new['Dest']:
        return False, "", ""
    total_time_change = time_change(old["DepCentral"], new["DepCentral"]) + \
        time_change(old["ArrCentral"], new["ArrCentral"])
    if abs(total_time_change) <= 50:
        return True, total_time_change, "other fields that changed"
    else:
        return False, "", ""
```

Loop through all the rows in the old and new table and compare them. With the size of the data you mentioned, looking through everything should be okay.

```
def compare_tables(old, new_df):
    if 'PK' not in old.columns:
        # use the current index as the starting PK
        old['PK'] = old.index
    for _, old_row in old.iterrows():
        print("Looking at row:")
        print(old_row.T)
        pk = old_row['PK']
        best_match = None
        best_match_time_change = float('inf')
        for _, new_row in new_df.iterrows():
            is_match, time_change, old_changes = check_match(old_row, new_row)
            if is_match and (time_change < best_match_time_change):
                best_match_time_change = time_change
                best_match = new_row
        print("The best match is:")
        if best_match is not None:
            print(best_match.T, best_match_time_change)
        else:
            print("no matches found")
        print()
        print()
```

loop through all the pairs of tables:

```
all_tables = [table_1, table_2, table_3, table_4]
for old, new_df in zip(all_tables, all_tables[1:]):
    compare_tables(old, new_df)
```